# c# how to get the cover art of a mp3 file into a picturebox windows forms

Tags: c#, mp3, wmplib

I am trying to make an mp3 application using WMPlib in windows forms.
Now I want to put the cover art of the mp3 file into a picturebox.
I did some research over the internet, but it was with different libraries and I could not figure out how to use them or implement them into windows forms.

I tried several things like

```
private void getImageFromSong()
{
    System.Drawing.Image currentImage = null;

    // In method onclick of the listbox showing all mp3's
    TagLib.File f = new TagLib.Mpeg.AudioFile(file);
    if (f.Tag.Pictures.Length > 0)
    {
        TagLib.IPicture pic = f.Tag.Pictures[0];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pic.Data.Data);
        if (ms != null && ms.Length > 4096)
        {
            currentImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            // Load thumbnail into PictureBox
            AlbumArt.Image = currentImage.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        ms.Close();
    }
}
```

and

```
pbSongImage.ImageLocation = paths[lbSongs.SelectedIndex];
```

I really did not know how to do it, or how to use the Taglib.

Comment: Now which: TagLib or WmpLib?

Comment: I use the following one
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();